# What happens outside radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

A real power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ has radius of convergence $R$. I am able to prove that for any real number $r>R$, the sequence $|a_n|r^n$ must be unbounded. Must it also tend to $\infty$? Please give me some hints, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$ for $n$ even, and let $a_n=1$ for $n$ odd.

Then the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is $1$, but for fixed $r\gt 1$ it is not the case that $|a_n|r^n\to\infty$.